# Download VS Studio 2008 [2021]

Tags: visual-studio

I am looking to download 2008 for a legacy project. However, the download [Page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=7873) doesn't seem to have an installation file anymore, only a `Windows 2008 overview.pptx`. Are there any other download locations?

Comment: For end of life products, you have to be a subscription user so as to download it from Microsoft. Contact Microsoft support (http://support.microsoft.com) if you lost the original installation media. They might verify your license key and show you how to download it.

Comment: AnonymousCreator no unfortunately not. @LexLi, thank you, you can set this to answer.